# How to get path of appsettings.json in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to get path of `appsettings.json` file, but I get null, instead of the string.

I have clean architecture (different assemblies) in my project. I have an infrastructure and presentation layer (controllers, DTO's and configuring pipeline `Program` class). I need to get path of presentation layer to use it in the infrastructure layer.

In my infrastructure layer I have this `DbContextFactory`:

```
public class DbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MainDbContext>
{
    public MainDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        string? basePath = DependencyInjection.AppSettingsPath; //Here is null
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                            .SetBasePath(basePath!)
                            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional:false)
                            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.Development.json", optional:true)
                            .Build();

        var dbContextBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MainDbContext>();
        var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("MainConnection");
        dbContextBuilder.UseNpgsql(connectionString);

        return new MainDbContext(dbContextBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

I want to get path to the `appsettings.json`, but I get null, how to avoid it and assign path to the `appsettings.json` from presentation assembly to infrastructure?

I've tried something like that (in the infrastructure layer):

```
public static class DependencyInjection
{
    public static string? AppSettingsPath;

    public static void AddInfrastructure(this IServiceCollection services, 
                                        IConfiguration config, 
                                        string appSettings)
    {
        AppSettingsPath = appSettings;  // Here is path assigning, but I get null
        
        var connectionString = config.GetConnectionString("MainConnection");
        services.AddDbContext<MainDbContext>(options => 
            options.UseNpgsql(connectionString, x => 
                x.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(DependencyInjection).Assembly.GetName().Name)));
    }
}
```

`Program` class:

```
builder.Services.AddInfrastructure(builder.Configuration,Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()); //Trying to assign path of the Presentation layer
```

Comment: Why do you think you _"need to get path of appsetings.json file"_ surely anything that it contained would be available via the injected `IConfiguration`

Comment: I've never seen a layer configure it self, nor the need for it to configure itself.  That's actually the point of dependency injection, to inject dependencies.  If you have a need for settings in a config file, those should be injected into your layers.

Comment: @phuzi please, turn on your monitor,brains and read the question :)

Comment: I agree with @phuzi, you shouldn't need it.  Your 'answer' is probably only correct for your development environment, and will fail later on.  Your `DependencyInjection` class is doing things that are not necessary (you should follow the existing patterns, rather than inventing your own).

Comment: @Neil you are wrong. phuzi got me wrong answer. Because working with IConfiguration it tried to find appsettings.json in Infrastructure folder when it is located in Presentation. So, this guy didn't even read the question :)

Comment: You are not following the standard patterns, which is why unusual things are happening.  The fact that you 'got it working' is more by luck than design.   Why is it looking for appsettings.json in the infrastructure folder? Why are you running from /username/projectname?  Probably because you've got some other setting wrong.  Have you got a launchsetting that starts the program in the wrong folder?

Answer (score 0):

I solve it. Thanks for help guys. I just got parent folder and used Path.Combine to get folder with Presentation layer;

```
  //  /username/projectName/
    string? parent = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).ToString(); //folder of whole project
//    /username/projectName/Presentation/ <- That's where appsettings.json located
    string? basePath = Path.Combine(parent,"Presentation"); //folder of presentation layer
```